# How to get ID in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to bind the id in the url to my FromBody object. Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("draft/{id:int}/save")]
public IHttpActionResult SaveCustomRecallDraft([FromBody] CustomRecallDraft request)
{
  return Ok();
}
```

I have an `id` property in my CustomRecallDraft object. But when I make the web request the the id field is null. Its a nullable id. here is my alternative code

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("draft/{id:int}/save")]
public IHttpActionResult SaveCustomRecallDraft([FromUri] int id, [FromBody] CustomRecallDraft request)
{
  return Ok();
}
```

This code works. The id field is not null. But how can I bind to the id field in my CustomRecallDraft object. I do not want two parameters.

Comment: If you don't want the ID from the URL, then why have it defined as part of your route?

Comment: I do want the ID. But I want it to bind to my CustomRecallDraft object. It will only bind to [fromuri]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("draft/{id:int}/save")]
public IHttpActionResult SaveCustomRecallDraft([FromBody] CustomRecallDraft request)
{
  //request.id is the {id:int} from the uri
  return Ok();
}
```

Based on all the documentation I've read about attribute routing (for example, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) and [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)) that can't be done.

The best you could do is use the FromUri parameter, and set request.id = id. Or just enforce that they're both the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could write custom Model Binder for your CustomRecallDraft, but that would  probably be an overkill though...